# pretty URl via htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

wana to turn this URL:

```
http://domainname.com/service_provider_list.php?loc=chhattisgarh-1&query=plumber-12
```

into this URL:

```
http://domainname.com/chhattisgarh-1/plumber-12
```

via htacess how it's possible please help

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /service_provider_list.php?loc=$1&query=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Read this tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rule is okay but you have to tell apache that incoming request is not a directory or file because apache first search for existing file which may lead to 404 not found, try with below,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ service_provider_list.php?loc=$1&query=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: i m new in htacess so how i tell apache that incoming request is not a directory or file

Comment: By using above rule.

Comment: but it showing 404 not found...

Comment: See here it is working http://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=32bf46eb-48d3-5d17-9ad3-e5687d51ff96

Comment: thnks buddy now it's working.. thanks a lot

Comment: when i m turning into hompage then it's not working proply <a href="../">main_index.php</a>         and htacess code RewriteRule    ^/?$  main_index_page.php   [NC,L]

Comment: What is the link of home page you might have to change the link old links with new links and clear cache of browser.

Comment: okkk after clearing cache it's working

Comment: when i m adding another page then it's calling first htacess code means when i m clicking second htacess URl then it call first URL




RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ professional_search_page.php?loc=$1&query=$2 [NC,L]


RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ professional_list_page.php?loc=$1&ID=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: Man, you are not done yet every time you add new rule please clear your browser cache.

Comment: i added new rule... for second URl but still it's calling first URL

Comment: If pattern for both the uri will be same then it will call first rule and ignore second rule you have to change your pattern and choose some other rewritten uri.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /service_provider_list.php?loc=$1&query=$2 [L]
```